# Reply from Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm making a GET request:

```
public interface CheckUserInDBRequest {
@GET("api/checkUserInDB.php")
Call<ResponseBody> searchForUser(
        @Query("login") String login,
        @Query("pass") String pass
);
}
```

And I get the answer true || false in json, according to whether there is a user in the database or not.

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://kurusa.zhecky.net/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

CheckUserInDBRequest client = retrofit.create(CheckUserInDBRequest.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = client.searchForUser (
        UserLogin.getText().toString(),
        UserPass.getText().toString()
);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Here is just the output of `okHttp3`. I do not understand how to get a normal answer.

Comment: What do you mean for "normal answer"? You are already getting it using `response.body()`

Comment: @MatPag, I get `okHttp3` using `response.body()`. But in `checkUserInDB.php` I return json object

Comment: How is structured your JSON response? Show an example

Comment: @MatPag, it's very simple: `{"isSet":"true"}` || `{"isSet":"false"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a class representing your `JSON` object

```
public class UserResult {
    public boolean isSet;
}
```

Restructure your `Retrofit` call in this way

```
@GET("api/checkUserInDB.php")
Call<UserResult> searchForUser(
        @Query("login") String login,
        @Query("pass") String pass
);
```

Then in your code:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<UserResult> call, @NonNull Response<UserResult> response) {
        if (response.isSuccesfull()) {
            UserResult result = response.body();
            //use the value result.isSet where you need it
        } else {
            //something is broken
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<UserResult> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't use `result` or `result.isSet`. Android Studio gives an error `cannot resolve method  makeText(kurusa.mainapp.MainActivity...)`

Comment: You had left some part of the `Toast` method somewhere, please comment out the `Toast` part and try again

Comment: still not working :c but for some reason if write some string instead of `result.isSet` it's working

Comment: did you mean that this if(result.isSet){//ok}else{//not ok} not worked with you

Comment: Are you sure that your REST is responding correctly? Test it on the browser to be sure

Comment: this response  {"isSet":"true"} || {"isSet":"false"} should be {"isSet":true} || {"isSet":false}

Comment: @ALTegani, yep) I forgot that Java is strictly typed language. Before I wrote in php

Comment: @Біпач is everything ok

Comment: @ALTegani, if it was question — yes

Comment: glad for you @Біпач

Comment: @Біпач You can accept the answer clicking the check near the arrows if this helped you ;)